# Small stakes $1-$2 $200 Cap - What to do inside straight flush draw?

Tags: nlhe, live, nl200

This is a Monday night game, so players aren't to splashy, everyone is playing pretty tame somewhat of a laggy, passive table.  I am able to take advantage with some aggressive 
bets and increase my $200 buyin to $450.

Then this hand happens:

I have around $450 in front and I am in late position.  Preflop action starts with a limp of $2 UTG, araise to $7 1st Mid position, Villain 1 stack size about $90, and called by 2nd Mid Position, Villian 2 stack size $350). I call the $7 raise with 7♣ 8♣ and there were
another two callers (both smallish stacks of less than $120) behind.

Flop

T♣ A♠ 6♣

Check to the raiser, Villian 1, who bets $20 then Villian 2 raises to $60.

What do you do here?  There are two additional players with action behind you, and the original raiser.

Spoiler Outcome below:

> If my $60 call would have closed action this round to let me peel another card, I would have made the call. I would have been willing to gamble if Villain 2 didn't have $350 stack size. But with original raiser still with action to allow for the re-raiser to shove for $350, I folded and one person after I called.  Villain 1 shoves for his remaining stack and Villain 2 calls and other calls.
>
> Turn comes 9♣.  ***DAGNABBIT***
> Other gets all-in for his remain stack Villain 2 calls.
>  River 6♥.
> So the boards is T♣ A♠ 6♣ 9♣ 6♥. 
>
> Villain 2 goes, "Whew! I made it." and he flips over A♣ 6⋄ for a boat (he flopped two pair).  Other players muck, I assume with flush draws or even A with good kicker.
>
> Afterward, I told the players, I folded the straight flush and a few of them said the would have made the call.   I wanted to get your read to see if I did the right thing.

Comment: Fold is good. I agree with Herb.

Comment: Did you even consider raising?

Comment: No, raising would definitely open up to be re-raised allin by the bigger stack, I think I got all the information need with the re-raise, either I am open to calling an allin or not with this particular draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty easy fold. You've got a bet and a raise in front of you. You aren't guaranteed to have the best flush, so you would need to hit a 9, and hope that no other clubs hits, or hit the 9:clubs: exactly, and you aren't getting near the right odds.

Comment: I added what I did and the resulting action to the question.  FYI

Comment: @Herb would you fold if it was 3 clubs on the board, based on the logic that we arent guaranteed to have the best flush, also?

Comment: @sakon that's a rather broad question. depends on the cards, betting and my read. If it was the 4 of clubs: or 5 of clubs, I might peel one off.

Answer (score 2):

You flat 78s in middle position and flop a gutshot straight flush draw. This is one of the best boards that 78s can flop so i would not be too quick to fold it.

Preflop V1 c-bets into 4 players for ~2/3 pot, V2 reraises. Generally i would be quite cautious about their ranges here but V2 (in hindsight) calls an early raiser out of position with A6o, so you should not be afraid of too many monsters. You are most afraid of AXs of clubs, as you have decent equity against any other holding, even sets. There are also not too many combination of AXs (if AJs+ reraises preflop) and you hold blockers.

V1 is too shortstacked to reopen the betting by shoving, so worst case scenario you call off the shove from V1 for $83 into a pot of ~$270. V2 here has $260 so you still have decent stack size to make plays on the turn.

Based on the play you describe (since V2 had the Ac), everyone is calling very light and the table is very loose, 78s is an ok hand to call, although EV+ i expect the variance here to be very high. So it probably also ok to fold since you only committed $7 pre-flop, and take better spots elsewhere.